# DNS query limit WinServer 2008R2

Tags: domain-name-system, rate-limiting

**Situation:**
I am currently seeing a huge wave of incoming DNS requests arriving in burst of around 85 queries per 2-3 seconds from one IP. Then another IP sends a new wave and so on (currently my DNS service is turned off, so that it does not take part in what looks like another amplification attack).

**Question:**
Is there a way to set a query limit per IP?

It is very unlikely that the same client needs to resolve more than 2 or 3 domains within a second, so that sounds like a reasonable step.

Comment: How are you certain this is unlikely?  Perhaps they are running a script or application that performs dns lookups.

Comment: 85 querries over 2-3 seconds doesn't sound that malicious. Is it querries for the same FQDN?

Comment: Yes, all for the same FQDN: directedat.asia: type ANY, class IN

Comment: When you say inbound, to you mean from the Internet, or internally?  Just asking, as it's possible to tunnel data through DNS queries.

Comment: Yes, from external IPs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No shipping version of Windows Server has any built-in functionality to do rate-limiting like you're looking for, either in the IP stack or in the DNS server. You're stuck putting a firewall that can rate-limit in front of the Windows machine if you want this type of functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Philip is is possible that you are running a public Recursive DNS server?

I see that you currently have disabled your DNS service but your IP is most likely still in the 'servers to abuse' list of criminals.

What you can do:

- Check if your public IP is listed on: openresolverproject.org
- Disable recursion on your DNS server completely or only listen on an internal interface. 
  See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755068.aspx
- Have a look at Bind DNS server under Linux. Its free and allows you to configer from what subnets you want to allow recursion.

Blog post on directedat.asia domain: http://dnsamplificationattacks.blogspot.com/2013/05/domain-directedatasia.html